# Sql - Stored Procedure with While statement

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop, sql-update, procedure

i'm trying to update some columns values using a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdataObjectivesPosition] 
@idGoal int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @count int 
    SET @count = 1

    WHILE exists (SELECT * From Objective Where IDgoal = @idGoal)
    Begin
      Update [Tasks] Set Position=@count
      SET @count = @count + 1
    End
 END
 GO
```

But i get an infinite loop, i think its because of while expression.
So how can I create this procedure correctly ? Please help me

Example:

### Name   Position

tskA     -   4

tskB   -     5

tskc       -     7

I want that the procedure sets the position to 1 , 2 , 3 , .......

Comment: Why should the condition in the `while` change?

Comment: I dont know, but the while never ends

Comment: Of course it never ends - your while condition has always the same result. To end the loop it has to be `false`. But the select in the while always returns something because it is always the same select.

Comment: Yes, i realise that. But my doubt is why can i put in the while statement just the needed rows and update the value inside While.

Comment: Ok, your logic right now reads like this: "If the value of @idGoal exists in the table, then continue this loop". Now the only way that this loop will stop is if that value stops existing in the Objective table. This is why you are running into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop at all to achieve what you want, you can do this using the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name)
    FROM    Tasks
)
UPDATE  CTE
SET     Position = rn;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30e46/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SQL Server solution I recently discovered.

```
DECLARE    @Count    INT = ( 
    SELECT  ISNULL(MAX([Position]),0) 
    FROM    [Objective] 
    )

UPDATE [Objective] 
SET     @Count = [Position] = @Count + 1
WHERE  [Position] IS NULL
```

It uses double assignment (`SET @a = @b = @a + 1`).

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/502a7/2)

[For more information](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2013/05/28/increment-a-variable-in-the-set-clause-of-an-update-statement-t-sql.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20jamiet%20%28Jamie%20Thomson%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I solve the problem using a cursor - for each row i set the new position based on incremental counter